# Microsoft Access Query Syntax Access (using IN clause within an IN clause)

Tags: ms-access

Hi I have had a problem with the following query.
I am using two `IN` clauses to find the `type=LEFT` for only `type=JOIN` has occurred once. However, the code is breaking.

Ultimately, I am trying to find how many animals left the Zoo without ever JOIN the cage. Thus, it outdates the database knowledge as I have added animals leaving without the join date
[image: jointable]

I believe the following code should be the resolution however it is not working
To my understanding I need an IN clause within an IN clause

```
SELECT animal8001.animalname, join8001.type, join8001.joindate
FROM carer8001 INNER JOIN ((cage8001 INNER JOIN (animal8001 INNER JOIN join8001 ON animal8001.animalid = join8001.animalid) ON cage8001.cageid = join8001.cageid) INNER JOIN care8001 ON cage8001.cageid = care8001.cageid) ON carer8001.carerid = care8001.carerid
WHERE (((join8001.type) In (SELECT join8001.type 
                                FROM   animal8001 
                                       INNER JOIN join8001 
                                               ON animal8001.animalid = 
                                                  join8001.animalid 
                                GROUP  BY join8001.type, 
                                          animal8001.animalid 
                                HAVING ( ( ( join8001.type ) = "join" ) 
                                         AND 
        ( ( Count(join8001.type) ) = 0 ) ))))
GROUP BY animal8001.animalname, join8001.type, join8001.joindate
HAVING (((join8001.type)="LEFT"));
```

Comment: Paste the query into your question.  Otherwise it is very hard to read.

Comment: It is pasted? im confused

Comment: @PandaPlaysAll He means to paste it as text, so it can be copied and formatted etc.

Comment: You should: 1 - select your  SQL text, eventually pressing your left mouse and dragging; 2 - Press CTRL + C to copy it to clipboard; 3 - Edite your Stackoverflow question and paste the text of your  SQL command, pressing CTRL + V

Comment: Done! I added the sql code, please note that its updated to match what I am trtying to do

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Access? The tag says MySQL, the title says Access.

Comment: Im using Access.

Comment: Ok. After reformatting your command using http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm, selecting Ms Access e pressing Format, the output showed a deeply nested querie, hugely complex. In my opinion, you will need to restart. In order to get help, you will need to share with us some samples of your tables, so one can get proper insight of what is really your goal. I am quite sure you are look for something rather simple.

Comment: I added what I am working on currently. That should be a simplified version but it is still breaking

Comment: Added the Pictures of the tables for sample data

Comment: You should post data as text table not image. As well as desired output from given sample. For instance, animal 3 shows LEFT but no JOIN, animal 38 shows JOIN then LEFT but not another JOIN. Should both animals be in output?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know which animals have a LEFT record with no JOIN records ever, simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AnimalCages.AnimalID
FROM AnimalCages
WHERE (((AnimalCages.AnimalID) Not In (SELECT AnimalID FROM AnimalCages WHERE Type="JOIN")));
```

If you want animals which have no JOIN records at all as well as those which have JOIN but not following a LEFT, consider:

```
SELECT AnimalCages.JoinDate, AnimalCages.AnimalID, AnimalCages.Type
FROM (SELECT Max(AnimalCages.JoinDate) AS MaxOfJoinDate, AnimalCages.AnimalID
      FROM AnimalCages
      WHERE (((AnimalCages.Type)="JOIN"))
      GROUP BY AnimalCages.AnimalID) AS MaxJOIN 
RIGHT JOIN AnimalCages ON MaxJOIN.AnimalID = AnimalCages.AnimalID
WHERE (((AnimalCages.AnimalID) Not In (SELECT AnimalID FROM AnimalCages 
           WHERE Type="JOIN"))) OR (((AnimalCages.JoinDate)>[MaxOfJoinDate]));
```

Comment: shouldn't the WHERE clause of the main query also contain "LEFT" as condition: WHERE AnimalCages.type = "LEFT" AND AnimalCages.AnimalID NOT IN.... Also, why using a DISTINCT?

Comment: AnimalID is not returned if there are JOIN records so those with just LEFT records are retrieved and additional filter not required. Include Type field in SELECT if you want to see that. However, allowed for possibility of multiple LEFT records. If not, then exclude DISTINCT.